# SQL Month YTD and prior YTD data

Tags: sql, date, dbvisualizer

I am trying to write a query to return Month-To-Date data for the Current Year, and also the Previous Year.
Meaning I need data from `2017-07-01` to `2017-07-26` and also `2016-07-01` to `2016-07-26`.

However, my query currently returns data from `2017-07-01` to `2017-07-26` (correctly) but also returns data from `2016-07-01` to `2016-07-31` (incorrectly).

How can I have the data for the same time period (MTD) from two different years?

The table includes `date`, `day in quarter`, `year`, `quarter`, `month` and `week` but no day column...

```
SELECT
    data_up_to,
    date,
    year,
    month,
    sum(sales)
FROM
    salesdata.sales
WHERE
    MONTH = MONTH(NOW()) and 
    YEAR in (YEAR(NOW()), YEAR(NOW())-1, YEAR(NOW())-2) and
    date <= data_up_to
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go like this:

```
SELECT   year
       , month
       , sum(sales)

from     salesdata.sales

--Selecting were day in range with same month
WHERE    DAY(date) BETWEEN 1 AND DAY(data_up_to)
AND      MONTH = MONTH(NOW()) 
AND      YEAR IN (YEAR(NOW()), YEAR(NOW())-1)

--Group by Year, Month 
GROUP BY YEAR 
       , MONTH
```

When you want to refer to MTD of `NOW()` You can use:

```
SELECT   year
       , month
       , sum(sales)

from     salesdata.sales

--Selecting were day in range with same month
WHERE    DAY(date) BETWEEN 1 AND DAY(NOW())
AND      MONTH = MONTH(NOW())
AND      YEAR IN (YEAR(NOW()), YEAR(NOW())-1)

--Group by Year, Month 
GROUP BY YEAR 
       , MONTH
```

I deleteted date from the query in order enable the grouping by month and year.

Comment: thank you very much! I had to use the DAY(NOW()-1) because it was returning more data. i.e. today (8/1) I was getting data up to 8/2 with 0 values.

SELECT   year
       , month
       , sum(sales)

from     salesdata.sales

--Selecting were day in range with same month
WHERE    DAY(date) BETWEEN 1 AND DAY(NOW()-1)
AND      MONTH = MONTH(NOW())
AND      YEAR IN (YEAR(NOW()), YEAR(NOW())-1)

--Group by Year, Month 
GROUP BY YEAR 
       , MONTH

Comment: one thing to add: In order to simplify the search for correct answers on stackoverflow: If the answer was correct mark it as correct. That helps others with a similar problem finding the answers faster. regards